# Deal with spaces in this regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex

```
var reg = <font[^>]*>(?:\s*<(\w+)>\s*<\/\1>\s*|\s*)<\/font>
```

is being used in replace(reg, '') to remove empty font tags. It removes this

```
<font size="3"></font>
```

okay.

How can I modify it so it will remove

```
<font size="3"> </font>
```

or

```
<font size="3">&nbsp;</font>
```

or

```
<font size="3">    </font>
```

I want to be able to find all empty font tags with any number of spaces between the tags and replace with an empty string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: @OneNeptune did you even take a look at the question?

Comment: Is your string just the font tag or is there more HTML? Either way I wouldn't use Regex to parse HTML.

Comment: According to regexr.com, this regex will match `<font size="3"> </font>` and `<font size="3">    </font>`, but also `<font size="3"> <span></span>   </font>`.  New regex needed methinks.  Regex may not be the best way to do this, especially if you want to treat all types of white spaces as the same - What about line breaks? both unix and windows? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is find all empty font tags with any number of spaces between the tags and replace with an empty string, you can simplify your regex a bit. If as you've indicated with your current regex, you also want to catch one layer of empty tags within it, you can do as follows:

```js
var reg = /<font[^>]*>(?:\s|&nbsp;|<(\w+)>(?:\s|&nbsp;)*<\/\1>)*<\/font>/gi

var testStr = `<font size="3"></font>
<font size="3"> </font>
<font size="3">&nbsp;</font>
<font size="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font>
<font size="3">    </font>
<font size="3"><something>&nbsp;&nbsp;</something></font>`

console.log(testStr.replace(reg, ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<font[^>]*>(?:\s*<(\w+)>\s*<\/\1>\s*|\s*|(&nbsp;)+)<\/font>
```

as per your regex. it already catches spaces. I just added the nbsp;

regex101 link: https://regex101.com/r/4Msyv1/2

Comment: What if we have multiple `&nbsp;`?